# javascript forEach appears to be nonblocking

Tags: javascript, foreach, synchronous

Reading other posts here the consensus is the forEach should be synchronous and blocking.

However I must have done something strange in my code because it doesn't appear that way:

```
    var noDupes = false;  // should be true but force no inserts for now
    console.log('forEach');
    courses.forEach((course) =>
    {
        const promiseNoDupe = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        {
            dbo.collection("courses").findOne({ id: course.id }, (err, result) => 
            {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (result) { console.log('dupe'); return reject('dupe'); }
                console.log('nodupe');
                resolve('nodupe');
            });
        });

        noDupes &= promiseNoDupe.then(() =>
        {
            console.log('true promise');
            return true;
        }).catch(() =>
        {
            console.log('false promise');
            return false;
        });
    });
    console.log('End forEach');

    if (noDupes)
    {
        console.log('Inserting many');
        dbo.collection("courses").insertMany(courses, (err, result)  =>
        {
            if (err) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
            res.send(courses);
        });   
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('No Dupes allowed');
        res.status(400).send('Inserting duplicate ID not Allowed!');
    }
```

Console output:

```
forEach
End forEach
No Dupes allowed
nodupe
true promise
nodupe
true promise
```

The end forEach is executed before the promise is completed and before any of the internal processing is conducted! Subsequently the logic waiting on the promise is processing ahead of time.

I'm not sure what is going wrong but I'm trying to wait for the completion of all checks in the forEach before committing any new records.

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach` is synchronous and blocking: it synchronously invokes a callback function for every element and runs that callback to completion.

Comment: `forEach` is synchronous. `dbo.collection().findOne()` is **not**

Comment: map() an array of promises instead of using forEach...then use `Promise.all() ` and check dupes inside the `then()` which won't fire until all the mapped promises have resolved

Comment: forEach is synchronous. dbo.collection().findOne() is not. Accepted but the findOne is now Promised!!!

Comment: _"but the findOne is now Promised"_  why do you think that would make a difference? The code is still asynchronous

Comment: @Phil "why do you think that would make a difference?" Because a Promise can be used to wait for completion of async code!?!?!?! I'm reading from a tutorial.  Maybe I'm not clearly understanding the tutorial!

Comment: A `Promise` just gives you something to return, allowing you to implement more of a consumer / supplier relationship between your components. It's an evolution of the _callback-hell_ type of async code (demonstrated in your `dbo` object). The code is still asynchronous in that the functions passed to `.then()` are still executed at a later time and regular process execution carries on without waiting

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to charlietfl for steering me towards map() and Promise.all().

Here is the working code:

```
    var dupePromises = courses.map((course) => 
    {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        {
            dbo.collection("courses").findOne({ id: course.id }, (err, result) => 
            {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (result) return reject(false);
                resolve(true);
            });
        }).then(() =>
        {
            return true;
        }).catch(() =>
        {
            return false;
        });
    });

    Promise.all(dupePromises).then((results) =>
    {
        if (results.every((isnotDupe) => { return isnotDupe /* == true */ }))
        {
            dbo.collection("courses").insertMany(courses, (err, result)  =>
            {
                if (err) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
                res.send(courses);
            });
        }
        else{
            res.status(400).send('Inserting duplicate ID not Allowed!');        
        }
    });
}
```